# How to correctly rasterize a polygon which crosses 180E longitude?

Tags: raster, gdal, polygon, rasterization

I want to rasterize a polygon wich crosses 180E lon with gdal_rasterize.

[image: Polygon example]

The polygon is in the WGS84 projection.
I used the following command:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -of GTiff -ot Byte -ts 1500 1500 in.shp out.tif
```

But resulting raster is looks like this:

[image]

I tried to use different projections etc. but result is the same.

How can i do it in 'proper' way? Any solution will be good, not just gdal.

Comment: Use a projection that makes sense for your domain,  longlat is a weird non-projection and rarely has sensible properties for any application.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17987/664 for one way to approach this kind of problem.